# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerText') at app.js:2186:27

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, axios

when i use axios in my node app to change the cart icon value it works but after the page refresh/reload. but it should work without page reload please help me to fix this problem. github link for my project check here to understand resources->js->app.js [click here](https://github.com/RamenManna/Realtime-Food-Order-Webapp)
app.js

```
import axios from 'axios'import Noty from 'noty'let addToCart = document.querySelectorAll('.add-to-cart')let cartCounter = document.querySelector('#cartCounter')function updateCart(food) {axios.post('/update-cart', food).then(res => {cartCounter.innerText = res.data.totalQtynew Noty({type: 'success',timeout: 1000,text: 'Item added to cart',progressBar: false,}).show();}).catch(err => {new Noty({type: 'error',timeout: 1000,text: 'Something went wrong',progressBar: false,}).show();})}

addToCart.forEach((btn) => {btn.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{

    let food=JSON.parse(btn.dataset.food)
    updateCart(food)
    
})

})
```

problem that shows in the inspect console

```
app.js:2186 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerText')     at app.js:2186:27 (anonymous) @ app.js:2186 Promise.then (async) updateCart @ app.js:2185 (anonymous) @ app.js:2205
```

It works but after the page reload/refresh then my cart value incremented otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using functional components, you need to use the useEffect handler. If you are using class components, you need to use the componentDidMount() property.

```js
// In Functional Component
useEffect(() => {
  // Code you want to run when the component mounts
}, []);

// In Class Component
componentDidMount() {
  // Code you want to run when the component mounts
}
```